# Toshiba Satellite P850 FN-Keys not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, toshiba-satellite, function-keys

I could solve several other issues with my laptop thanks to this forum. The only thing I can't figure out is the non working FN-Keys for the brightness. Volume control is fine.

Two things I found out so far:

1) I might have to update my BIOS (would only work in windows and I'm running 14.04 Ubuntu only)

2) I have to "re-program" every key myself, using this "recording" function in the Terminal, unfortunately I send my laptop to sleep when I press F4. And anyway this option seems very complicated.

Thanks for your help!
Urs

Answer (score 2):

This has fixed it:

1) Edit /etc/default/grub and change this variable:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=legacy"

2) Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add this line at the end of the file:

blacklist toshiba_acpi

3) Update the grub config file:

sudo update-grub

4.) Reboot.