# Brightness keys not working and no obvious interface for adjustment either

Tags: 14.04, laptop, brightness, backlight, toshiba

New to Ubuntu and so far pretty happy with it but one niggle is the brightness controls do not seem to work. I have looked at fixes on here + google but nothing seems to get it right. Mostly effecting GRUB config in different variations and none show any change except for this one
[Toshiba Satellite P850 FN-Keys not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451165/toshiba-satellite-p850-fn-keys-not-working)
which fixes the keys presses and displays the brightness modal but does not actually affect the screen brightness.

The problem is that there seem to be no UI controls for brightness in my fresh install of ubuntu on to a Toshiba C50-B-14D laptop. The keys for brightness do not work either (F2 + F3) and the increas brightness button seems to send the laptop in to sleep mode.

I have been in to sys/class/backlight and have found both video0 and intel folders here

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and type `ls /sys/class/backlight`. Note the exact name of the Intel interface. In my case it is `intel_backlight`.

Then type `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

Copy and paste the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Edit the option line as necessary.

Logout and in again.

Source: http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: Wow. I don't what was different but I found this page before and followed it's instructions to no avail. It is working now. Thank you very much. Perhaps I entered it incorrectly last time.

Answer (score -1):

For HP G60:

I had no files in the backlight folder so I searched for that and found the information in the Ubuntu wiki.

From there I followed the troubleshooting guides until it finally began to work after adding "apci_osi=" as a kernel parameter. Jeez.